# How do you add borderRadius to expo-blur BlurView?

Tags: expo

When you add

```
style = {{
  borderRadius: 10,
}}
```

nothing happens.
How do you get the borderRadius to work?

Answer (score 0):

The style props are passed to a normal View wrapping the `BlurView`.

Add `overflow: 'hidden'` to hide the BlurView's square edges.

```
style = {{
  borderRadius: 10,
  overflow: 'hidden'
}}
```

<sub>*Hat tip @ouwargui* [on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22385#issuecomment-1535560680).</sub>